# can SVN use slash "/" as the path seperater under MS Windows?

Tags: svn

Under MS windows command prompt, when you type a svn command, such as: svn status. 
It will show the change state and the path name. But it is using "\" as the path delimiters.

Is there a way to use "/" as the path delimiters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this answer we will add a new command, which is executed calling `svnst` on the bash command-line.

To do so, open `~/.bashrc` with a editor.

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

and add at the end of the file

```
function svnst() { svn status $@ | sed 's:\\:/:g'; }
```

After saving the file, open a new bash command-shell so the changes can take effect.

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11828573/406423) if you have trouble [saving and exiting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11828573/406423) vi.

Blatantly copied from [Gedrox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/369330/gedrox)s comment from the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10514818/406423) here, which *almost* works.

Answer (score 0):

One solution (maybe not the best one) is to run `svn` on `cygwin`.

Comment: At least `svn` 1.7.8 on `cygwin` uses backslash delimiters as well.

Comment: Still, you can add function
    `function svnst() { svn status $@ | sed ‘s:\\:/:g’ }`
in the ~/.bashrc file and use cygwin. Restart cygwin after the change.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed incorrectly that svnstat would be picked up by svn. Upon closer examination @MadMike solution worked for me but I needed to use the alias like so:

```
svnst -u
```

Thanks @MadMike