# How do I save my changes and exit Vim?

Tags: git, vim, github

I am trying to post a commit to my forked repository. I have gotten to the point where I have to enter a commit message. Vim appears, I typed in the message that I would like to be displayed but I don't know where to go from there. Do I save the message then push? If so, how would I go about doing that? I looked up Vim commands for saving, but they appear be characters rather than commands. Help is always appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You can also use any command-line editor other than vim if you'd prefer, by setting `$GIT_EDITOR` or `$EDITOR`, or with `git config --global core.editor command_name`. (See the bottom of [the git-commit man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html).)

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I exit Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-do-i-exit-vim)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To write and quit in Vim:

1. Press escape.
2. Type ":x".
3. Press enter.

Follow this with `git push`.

Comment: WOO! it works, I am so excited.

Answer (score 6):

If you are unfamiliar with vim, I would recommend running this command:

```
git config --global core.editor "nano --tempfile"
```

This will run `nano` instead. It feels more natural and you can exit it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Answer (score 5):

To save in `vim` you should be in `command` mode, you can do it pressing Esc key.

Once you can use `w` to save and `q` to exit, but first you must type ":". The whole sequence:

```
:wq
```

or just the abbreviation:

```
:x
```

Answer (score 5):

People have recommended using `:qa!`, `:wq` etc.

I recommend that instead you use the mapping `ZZ`, this will save your current file AND exit. :)

Here's a good, full guide to mappings: [http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-*Tutorial*(Part_1)](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_1%29)

Basically, you type `ZZ` in normal mode and it will save the current file, if it has unsaved changes, and it will quit Vim.

If you're new to Vim, I suggest you open `vimtutor` from your command line so that you can grasp the basics of Vim. :)

Comment: can you explain the benefits of using ZZ mapping. I am not familiar with the term mapping in regards to vim.

Comment: @ShaneKelsey Using the `ZZ` mapping is better because it accomplishes what `:w` and `:qa!` accomplishes. I'll explain in detail in the answer.

Comment: How does that make it better? It does the *same thing* as `:x` or `:wq`. It also is *not* equivalent to `!`; it will refuse to overwrite a file if it has changed on disk.

Comment: @meagar It is faster. :) And yeah it is different in that sense, but in those cases you can use `:x` and `:wq`, or you can remap `ZZ` in order to achieve what `:x` or `:wq` achieve. :)