# How do I leave the edit mode in ipython?

Tags: edit, ipython

After calling `edit 21:35` I can't manage to leave the mode. That is, `q` `esc` ect don't do it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize that this would open `vim` for editing. So this [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-to-exit-the-vim-editor) 
 on how to quit `vim`.

Comment: Actually `%edit` calls the editor defined by the environment variable `EDITOR` see http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.0.0/config/editors.html Hence, vi is only called if you are on an Linux sytem and don't have your `EDITOR` variable set. On Windows it would call notepad. (BTW: vi can be saved and closed using `:wq`)