# git vimdiff mergetool basic commands?

Tags: git, vimdiff, mergetool

I have executed `git mergetool` to try to resolve some merge conflicts.

It opens 3 text windows (within my SSH terminal) with different versions of code in each.

The code I want is in the window on the right.

How do I tell git to take this version and move on?

Here's the screen shot...[image]

Comment: Which merge tool are you using? A screenshot would allow us to tell.

Comment: The tool is vimdiff. I added a screenshot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-do-i-exit-vim#11828573

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-do-i-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-a-git-repository

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this blogpost](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim-resolving-merge-conflicts-with-vimdiff/):

> There are two basic strategies for reconciling a 3-way diff. You can either keep your cursor in the middle file, and run :diffget with the bufspec for the file containing the change you want to keep. Or you can position your cursor on the change that you want to keep, and run :diffput with the bufspec for the working copy file.

Now, a bufspec is a buffer number, a pattern for a buffer name or a part of a buffer name, like "v2" in "file.cpp.v2". If you type *2* plus CTRL+G, it shows you the buffer number and file.