# Can't exit Git commit in Windows

Tags: windows, git, vi

From Powershell I've called `git commit` and it presents me with

[image]

I typed the commit message (in yellow) but I have no idea what to do next. Pressing Enter just adds a newline to my input.
How do I complete the commit? I've been through several tutorials but none of them explained the next step.

**EDIT**: So I found I can press `:` to make the cursor jump to the bottom line, then type `wq` to complete the commit. What exactly is this? Is it correct? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: You can also use `:x<cr>` or just `ZZ` [no `<cr>` needed and which is shortand for the `:x`]. These have the virtue [over `:wq`] that they will terminate `vi` but will _not_ write to the file (i.e. change the mtime) unless [pending] changes have been made in the `vi` edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exit the VIM editor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-to-exit-the-vim-editor)

Comment: And if you prefer some other editor, see here for how to configure: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2596805/1615903

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After typing the message, press Escape to exit insert mode and then type ***:wq*** (**w**rite/save and **q**uit, or ***:q!*** if you want to cancel and return to the prompt). Alternatively, you can commit in one step by typing ***git commit -m "message"***