# How to exit the insert screen in mac terminal

Tags: git, vim, terminal

```
Merge branch 'develop' into peakfront

# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
#
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
# the commit.

"To get updated code in my branch"


-- INSERT --
```

I have typed this, but I cant find a way to save this and exit, so that I could work on terminal. What command am I to use here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exit the Vim editor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-to-exit-the-vim-editor)

Answer (score 40):

Press esc, then colon (:) and then enter on keyboard wq to save and exit.

If you wish to just quit, without saving, write q without w

Comment: You can mark answer as correct, if this is correct.

Comment: What the hell? is it vim?

Answer (score 7):

Steps:

1. Press ESC
2. Write :w
3. Write :q

Your text has been saved :)

Answer (score 3):

Escape should work, but I found myself in a weird scenario recently where at times my esc key was not working for exiting insert mode. I couldn't isolate the issue, but I did stumble across the fact thatif you **use option + left arrow or right arrow** (like you would in order to skip through or highlight expressions in a code editor), it leaves insert mode as well.

At least on my MacBook Pro (14-inch, 2021) with an M1 on which I did not tinker with keybindings at all.

Comment: This happened to me after updating vscode