# Trying to quit vi editor gives an error

Tags: vi

I am using `vi editor` to write scripts, however I have made a mistake deleting some lines of code without saving. Now I would like to undo the changes. The way I found to do that was to use the `u keystroke` to undo the changes and it worked fine.

Now I was thinking to just quit the vi editor  in the current state without saving the changes so I try

1. Press `Esc` key
2. Press `:q` to quit

It gives me an error

```
No write since the last change vi error while quitting
```

How do I get over with this error

Thanks for help.

Comment: Try `:q!` to ignore any changes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exit the Vim editor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-to-exit-the-vim-editor)

Comment: You also always can send foreground task to back job with `Ctrl+Z`, and then `kill %1`

Comment: @vp_arth Ctrl+Z doesn't help, but yeah :q! solves my problem, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an exclamation mark, i.e. `:q!`, to force exit without saving.

Comment: I was waiting for the 10min duration to get over as SO doesnt allow accepting a question before that

Comment: I didn't know that!  Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The error simply means the file has changed and you have not save the recent changes. Its like trying to quit MsWord without saving, it prompts a **Quit without saving changes?**. What you can do is

If you want to save your changes type `:w` and `q` respectively. This write you changes and quits vi.

If you want to quit without saving type `q!`. This will quit without saving your recent changes.

Comment: Thanks for the proper explanation,