# What are these things on my command line?

Tags: command-line

Can someone please tell me why do I get these weird characters as I type in my command line? If I press down a key I get ^[ and things like it.

Also, how can I quit vim mode? I can't click anywhere or make changes to the text.
[image: commandline]

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are in insert mode and it is expecting characters, so it converts the up and down buttons to those characters.

To quit vim:

Hit the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key; that goes into command mode. Then you can type

- `:q`  to quit (short for `:quit`)

You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11828573/7219974).