# How to close vim editor with non-zero return value?

Tags: vim

I have an `alias bed="vim ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc"` in my `.bashrc`. Now every now and then I'd like to run `bed` but return the `vim` with an exit status `1` so the source command doesn't execute.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Found the answer here : [How do I exit Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-to-exit-the-vim-editor)

You can do `:cq` to exit with a exit code 1 or `:cq 2` to exit with exit code 2.