# How to set breakpoints to all lines in a c# file in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, breakpoints

I am working with Visual Studio 2015.

I have a big c# class file with lot of properties and methods. I want to set breakpoints to all possible lines (set and get of properties, methods) at once. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

You could add `Debugger.Break()` on the end of every single line. Therefore you could use the search and replace function of visual studio and replace `\n` with `Debugger.Break()\n` (Remember activating the *regular expression* option). This would cause the debugger to break at every single line, even though you won't have an indicated breakpoint.

I don't think that there's a method to add normal vs breakpoints to every single line though, due to the fact that it's quite useless, considering that you normally just step through the code with *F11*.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for this,

steps to follow:

1) Add a break point on the first line of code you want to debug.

2) Run the application.

3) When you want to run the next line of code, Select Debug | Step Into

4) Repeat step #3 for each line of the code

Comment: Or press F10 or F11

Comment: And when the execution exits a sub/function? Where does it go then?

Answer (score 2):

Open a feature request with Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/suggest-a-feature?view=vs-2022

There should be a mode that visual studio can be put in so that it automatically stops on every line of code in a particular project.  This would be VERY valuable when you attach the debugger to a pre-existing process and you don't know where in the app is the current point of execution is, ie: web apps where you do not know the entry point.

Answer (score 1):

With vim (vsvim) you can set a breakpoint, move down a line, then repeat however many times you like, eg:

{Escape}qq:vsc Debug.ToggleBreakpoint{Enter}jq100@q

will set breakpoints on the next 100 lines

edit: here is example video, wouldnt let me embed gif https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqdRc.jpg

Comment: Works well enough if you're used to using VIM, otherwise https://stackoverflow.com/q/11828270/389424 ;-) . Too bad MS dropped macro support in VS.

Answer (score 0):

Step Into(F11) or use the Debugger.Break() or add breakpoint directly would be the workarounds for you, of course, I suggest you use the Step Into(F11) which was much more convenient.

If you could use the latest VS2017 version, it has a new feature "Run to Click" which is also a better workaround for you during debugging.

Actually you don't have to debug every line code, that's also the reason I suggest you use this new feature.

[image]

> ***Run to Click: Simply click the icon next to a line of code while debugging to run to that line. No longer set temporary breakpoints or
>   perform several steps to execute your code and stop on the line you
>   want. Now while stopped at a break state under the debugger, the Run
>   to Click icon subtly appears next to the line of code that your mouse
>   is hovered over. Move your mouse to the icon and click the button, now
>   your code will run and stop on that line the next time it is hit in
>   your code path. Turn it off from Debug> Options > Enable Run to
>   Click.***

Reference:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes