# Exit when used tag in Git

Tags: git, tags

I am begginner in Git. I study use Git when I use tag : git tag -a v1.0. I don't know write tag where and how to exit main menu. I can't back menu.
Thank you so much!
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZQkV.jpg)

Comment: Are you [trying to exit Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-to-exit-the-vim-editor)

Comment: thank you so much. I dit it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just press 'q' button to exit from interactive mode.

Comment: Thank you. I did it :)))

Answer (score 0):

First press the Esc button first to get out from INSERT MODE
Use anyone as per your needs

:wq - for save and quit

:q - for quit (it will not save what you changed on that file

:wq - save and quit for