# What is the difference between :q and :qa! in Vim?

Tags: vim

I'm quite new to Vim so I first checked the help.txt file to inform myself about Vim. Here I saw the following:

> Close this window:  Use ":q".
>      Get out of Vim:  Use ":qa!" (careful, all changes are lost!).

The first one closes Vim. The second one also. Wouldn't all changes also go with :q? To be clear, I use the vim GUI not a command prompt.

edit: It's more about the difference, not the actual meaning. The almost same explanation in the help.txt file confused me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exit the Vim editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-to-exit-the-vim-editor)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The key difference is the exclamation mark here. `:q` will warn you about unsaved changes and will not let you exit. `:q!` will not warn you.

See also `:help quit` (type that in vim)

Comment: Thank you, but what about :qa!

Comment: The `a` means 'all'. If you have multiple buffers loaded, `q` will quit the current visible one and jump to the next. `qa` will quit all buffers and exit vim.

Comment: A good habit I have learned into my finger is to quit Vim with: `:wqa`. Saves and quits all buffers, and the keys are all close to each other.

Comment: @oysteijo `:xa` is even shorter.

Comment: OP asked for something very specific and you answered whatever you felt to answer.

Answer (score 42):

I don't see any of the answers specifically addressing the meaning of 'a' so thought I'd contribute:

`:q` is quit, as you know, but warns you didn't save

`:qa`  is quit, all buffers, without saving but you'll get that same warning

`:qa!`  is quit all buffers, without saving, and without a warning

Comment: `w` is for "write".

Answer (score 10):

When you have some changes and use `:q`, it fails and throws an error stating `No write since last change`. In order to quit from the Vim without saving changes, you should write `:q!`, it will quit the Vim and `!` will work as a negation, which will negate the write operation.

When you fire `:qa!`, it quits the vim and doesn't throw an error mentioned above as you have added `!`. And there is no argument like `a` if you see `man vi`. (Just to note, arguments are case sensitive and -a and -A are treated differently)

In order to save the file and then quit the vim, you should use `:wq`, as it will first save the file and then quit the Vim.