# Putty Commands for editing XML file

Tags: unix

I need to edit a xml file in a server. How can I navigate to the path where the file is present in the server and edit it using putty commands. I am new to unix so if anyone could help me out.

Comment: [PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) is just a SSH client. Apart from establishing a connection to the server and moving the data back and forth, there is nothing it can help you with. What you need is a Linux/Unix tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

To move around in linux you need to use the change directory command which is: `cd /location/of/directory/`. If you then need to edit a file there are a number of editors which you can use. My preference is VIM which can be used by doing the following `vi file.xml`. Although VIM is not recommended if you are new to unix. Try using `nano filename.xml` instead if this makes it easier for you.

If you wish to edit a file directly without having to move to it's directory you can just do: `nano /path/to/file.xml`

Comment: Vim is an inbuilt editor which will be installed on your Unix server (although some people install it on their workstation to use as their text editor).

Comment: @harshit-naik this is a trap! Before starting `vi` read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11828270/4265352
:-D

Comment: Hence why i recommended that he used nano instead.

Comment: Ok I will take your suggestion too @axiac.. I have task of editing a xml file in a server. Instead of dragging the file to my desktop each time to edit and to upload it back. I want to figure out a way to edit it inside the server.Can anyone help with this?

Comment: The answer i have provided will allow you to do exactly that.

Comment: Lemme try it out. Will get back to you if I have issues @Lewis Browne

Comment: Okay, best of luck.

Comment: @Lewis Browne can u help with exact commands. I have used the cd command to navigate to the file path.What next?

Comment: You shouldn't need to, once you are in the directory of the file then do: `nano filename.xml`.

Comment: Should be fine with .xsl files.

Comment: I used nano filename.xml I am getting the error nano not found

Comment: Then it's not installed, what operating system is your Unix server?