# :wq! results in E212: Can't open file for writing Press ENTER or type command to continue

Tags: linux, bash, vim

I am just trying to exit my vim file with :wq! but it gives me the error:

`E212: Can't open file for writing 
Press ENTER or type command to continue`

I press enter or type anything and it goes back to editing the file. Is there something wrong?

I am now stuck in my text editor.

Comment: It's telling you that you can't write the file, just use `:q!` to exit without saving changes.

Comment: wow embarrassing. thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exit the Vim editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-to-exit-the-vim-editor)

Answer (score 6):

You can get more details about the error via `:help E212`:

> For some reason the file you are writing to cannot be created or overwritten.
>   The reason could be that you do not have permission to write in the directory
>   or the file name is not valid.

If you don't need the changes any longer, just `:q!` and be done with it. For multiple Vim arguments, there's also `:qall!`.

If you do want to keep the changes, one approach is to investigate the permissions issue, e.g. in another terminal or via the file explorer, and fix the issue (e.g. via `chmod` / `chown`).

Alternatively, you can persist the changes elsewhere via `:w /tmp/changes`, then `:quit` Vim, and then resolve the problem outside of Vim.

To address the "I'm stuck in Vim" (assuming it's not possible / tedious to start another session on the system): `:suspend` puts Vim in the background, and drops you into the original shell you started Vim from. `:shell` starts a *new* shell from inside Vim, to which you return via `exit`.