# Caret notation and control characters in Vim

Tags: vim, terminal

In Vim (or in a terminal?), control characters and their caret notation cannot be distinguished, like `Enter` vs. `C-M`. However, there is an only exception; `BS` vs. `C-H`.
Why are they only privileged?

For example, if you map `Enter` to `NOP`, also `C-M` will be mapped. Other many control characters have the same behavior. On the other hand, `BS` and `C-H` can be mapped to different keys respectively.

```
:map <Enter> <NOP> // also <C-M> will be mapped
:map <BS> <NOP>    // only <BS> will be mapped, <C-H> won't
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exit the Vim editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-to-exit-the-vim-editor)

Comment: @Eng_Farghly No, that's not what I mean. I love to use Vim, and I happened to know the fact above. I'd like to know the reason why that happen, just from curiosity.

Comment: Try the `ga` command?

Comment: My question didn't seem to be clear. I apologize for my insufficient explanation. I added an example.

Answer (score 4):

You can insert a backspace into a file by pressing <kbd>*control*</kbd><kbd>**`V`**</kbd> before the backspace.  In that case, vim (and most editors) will display it as **`^H`**.  But normally backspace is treated as a command (telling vim to do something, depending on the mode).

When moving the cursor in a file containing control characters, you can readily distinguish between a control character versus caret next to another character: as you move the cursor left/right, vim will move **two** columns for the control character, but **one** column for each of the caret and other character.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know all the nitty-gritty details, but basically (as I understand it) Vim uses an API to obtain the pressed keys that cannot distinguish between those different keys. For graphical applications like GVIM, all keys could be distinguished without problems; it's just a matter of switching to a more powerful (and GUI-only) API. For terminals, not all can actually distinguish between those keys (with `<BS>` / `<C-H>` the only exception). Many modern once can, though, it it again becomes a matter of switching to a more powerful API.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim release.

#### More details on the problem

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, it unfortunately isn't generally possible today to distinguish certain keys, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Comment: Do you know why the API which Vim uses makes an exception of `BS` and `C-H`?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `XK_BackSpace` keysym generally causes terminals to send ASCII DEL (`0x7F`), not ASCII BS (`0x08`, `^H`).  To balance things out, `XK_Delete` sends a sequence like `\033[3~`. Thus, unlike `XK_Tab`/`^I`,  `XK_BackSpace` and `^H` send completely different bytes.

Programs using the [terminfo](https://man.openbsd.org/terminfo.5) database can read the `kbs` and `kdch1` capabilities to know what Backspace and Delete send, respectively. You can see your terminal's value with `tput`:

```
$ tput kbs | sed -n l
\177$
```

`\177` is octal for ASCII DEL (see [ascii(7)](https://man.openbsd.org/ascii.7)).

Another method is to check the [termios(4)](https://man.openbsd.org/termios.4) structure, which controls the “cooked mode” used by e.g. `cat` to read input (unlike `bash` or `zsh`). This is what Vim does in [`get_tty_info`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/a906e8e1abf0a4c9a058ec5ee8a4c321a008cd41/src/os_unix.c#L3722) (`src/os_unix.c`), uh, after it checks [termcap(5)](https://man.openbsd.org/termcap.5), compares backspace and delete, and, uh, maybe calls `:fixdel`? But you get the idea.