# Git bash - how to exit

Tags: windows, git, github, git-bash

How do I exit a pull request in git bash on Windows? I just ran `git pull upstream master` and now I am being prompted to make a commit message. I have tried typeing `q`, `qw`, `wq`, `ctrl+c`, `esc` anything I can think of to get out of this but nothing returns me to the normal git shell. Bellow is a screen capture of my bash window.

[image: screen capture of my bash window]

Comment: That looks like Vim so.... possible duplicate of [How to exit the Vim editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-to-exit-the-vim-editor) Did you make sure you were in normal mode (hit `esc`) then type a colon before your commands (`:wq`)?

Comment: Omg, thank you I did not know I needed to hit colon first.