# Unable to "esc" vi editor

Tags: vi, google-cloud-shell

- In [google-cloud-shell]
- Entered vi ./.bashrc. File displayed in vi
- Entered "esc" to exit
- vi does not recognize esc. Can't exit

Comment: Are you familiar with `vi`? ESC is not a `vi` exit command. It's used to indicate you're done inputting text when in text input mode. To exit `vi`, type `:`, then `q`, then RETURN

Comment: I am but I'll admit that it's been a LONG time (running unix on super mini's back in the day).  I've even had a beer with Bill Joy. That said, the directions on the Cloud Shell quickstart say to press ESC then q! (https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/quickstart) but it doesn't hold focus on the shell.  Very weird.

However, the : pre-command works.  I will ping the Google folks on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Those directions may be in error (it happens). It's quite possible that the person who wrote those directions hasn't used `vi` in a long time or at all. ;) Standard `vi` is definitly a `:` followed by `q!` (The `!` means to quite and not save any possible pending changes). ESC is used in `vi` to end input, as I mentioned.

Comment: It is common practice for vi users to say "Press ESC then enter :wq". Pressing ESC is safe and ensures that you are in `command` mode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I exit Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-do-i-exit-vim)

Answer (score 2):

Type `:wq` to save and quit or `:q!` to quit, but don't save.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like other don't know the situation, I also have the same issue, currently what I do is:

1. click send key combination on upper right corner.
2. click Send key combination in list.
3. send `ctrl o` which is save file vi in insert mode.
4. then you regain `:` Ex command, which you can save your changes and exit but pressing `Esc` still does not change to normal mode.