# How to create a Linux user that logs in with a keypair

Tags: linux, ssh

That's how I am trying to do it:

**Step 1:**

- sudo adduser Philipp --disabled-password
- sudo su - Philipp
- mkdir .ssh
- chmod 700 .ssh
- touch .ssh/authorized_keys
- chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
- create keypair from AWS console

**Step 2:**

I am retrieving the public key for my keypair using:

- ssh-keygen -y
- copy & paste the public key

**Step 3**

- vim authorised_keys
- pasting the public key in 1 line
- in vim command :w
- in vim command :q

**UPDATE**

When I now try to the following in terminal:

ssh -i "keypair.pem" philipp@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx

I receive the following:

philipp@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx's password:

What am I doing wrong? 
With my main Linux User I am able to SSH the same way..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I exit the Vim editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-do-i-exit-the-vim-editor)

Comment: There's no "Mac" command for this, and this doesn't appear to have anything to do with Linux or `ssh`. You're just asking how to use `vim`.

Comment: @LoïcReynier No, because as soon as I copy&pasted the public key - and try to do anything, there is that blocking sound coming

Comment: If you're getting a weird response, that should be included in the body of your Q. You do know that issuing the `vim` cmd `:wq` will `:` goto-cmd mode, `w`rite the file, and `q`uit vim? You may need to press the Esc key to get in the correct mode. Good luck.

Comment: In any case, this isn't really a programming Q., so please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add user to your system using adduser
2. On your host generate keys : ssh-keygen
3. Copy public key to remote machine: ssh-copy-id user@host
4. Make changes in sshd_config on remote machine:

AllowUsers user@host or same username

Match User username
AuthenticationMethods 'publickey'

Comment: That similar to what I am doing and not working

Comment: ssh -i "keypair.pem" philipp@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx are you using both private and public?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with both.. I have created the private keypair for my instance in the EC2 console. After that I used terminal to generate the public key and placed it in the .ssh folder file authorised_keys

Comment: check if you have got running ssh-agent, if you are able you can send me sshd config, generate keys, unlock user account

Comment: I saw what the problem is.. the authorised_keys file is empty.. but why? How can I add it correctly if not with the steps above @Forbidden

Comment: Managed to add the public key into the authorized_keys file and now its all working.. thanks for your help!