# Problem in pushing code to github with git bash

Tags: git, github, git-bash

[image]

I got this screen. I have 2 queries
first, if you get this screen then how I can go back to the normal git prompt?
2nd how this error will be removed??

Comment: You hit the most common question on SO : [How do I exit the Vim editor ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-do-i-exit-the-vim-editor)  !!! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error. It's asking for a commit message. To enter a message on the first line, type `i` to go into insert mode, enter some text, hit `escape`, then type `:x` and enter.

You can bypass the prompt for a commit message by using the `-m` flag, as in `git commit -m 'changed some code'`.

[This](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-commit) explains what a commit is, and [this](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) explains how to change your configuration to use a different editor (that's Vim; you might want to use `nano` or something else).