# git commit --amend not opening a new tab in VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, commit, git-amend

I used to use `git commit --amend` and it used to open a new tab in VS Code where I can edit the commit and when I close this tab the commit is changed, but for some reason this doesn't happen any more.

Now when I use `git commit --amend` it doesn't open the new tab and displays the commit message in the command line, and I can't edit it there.

How can I have the VS Code tab back, or edit the message in the command line?

I tried to edit the message in the command line but nothing changed, I can't even quit this phase with Ctrl + C and I exit it by closing Powershell.

Comment: How to edit the message in the command line will depend on what program is running there to edit it. Based on your difficulty quitting it, maybe [Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11828270/3001761)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvisual-studio-code%5D+%5Bgit%5D+editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your default editor is not VS code. Run this command:

```bash
git config --global core.editor "code --wait"
```

The command will wait for the VS code file to be closed before returning to the command line.