# How do I exit GNU APL?

Tags: exit, apl, gnu-apl

> "I am stuck and cannot escape." - [jclancy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-do-i-exit-vim)

I've been using Dyalog workspaces to play with APL, but wanted to try it out on the CLI, so I downloaded GNU APL from homebrew to check it out. Works great!

Unfortunately, once launched, I can't figure out how to quit or even suspend the REPL.

I have tried:

- Searching [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/apl/apl.html) for the word "quit" ... it does not appear. (In the TOC, there's a section called "starting the REPL", but none called "stopping the REPL");
- I tried running these commands: `)QUIT`, `)EXIT`, `)STOP`, `)BYE`, `)DONE` with prefixes of both `)` and `]`, and no prefix at all;
- `ctrl-C`, `ctrl-D`, `ctrl-Z` are all disabled;
- I even tried `ctrl-x ctrl-c` and `esc :q`, just in case (they don't do anything).

(As a workaround, `kill -9 $pid` *did*  of course work and was rather satisfying).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *is* in the docs: section 1.2. (Keywords "stop" or "exit" – you were close!)

> #### 1.2 Starting APL
>
> Last things first: before explaining how to start APL, it is important to remember how to stop (i.e. exit) it. Neither <kbd>^C</kbd> nor <kbd>^D</kbd> will stop APL - they serve other purposes. Instead, you leave APL with the command `)OFF` (on a separate line) like this:
>
> ```
> )OFF
> ```
>
> If APL is computing a function (and possibly caught in an endless loop), then you may have to press <kbd>^C</kbd> (called ATTENTION in APL) in order to return to APL’s command mode and then give the `)OFF` command.